# Mongoose database query updating value in database while fetching records (Read operation)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const applicationQuerys = isAdmin
    ? Application.find()
    : Application.find({
        'data.active': true,
        'log.created_by': activeUserId,
      });

  applicationQuerys.setOptions({ lean: true }).populate({
    path: 'data.candidate_id',
    select: '_id data.firstname data.lastname',
  });
filter logic...
.
.
.
.

applicationQuerys.where(updatedFilter);
.
.
.
.    
return Promise.all(
    applicationList.map(async (doc) => {
      const { _id, data, log } = doc;
      const candidateData = await populatedCandidate(data.candidate_id);
      const appLog = await getLogsData(log);

      !doc.data.active && Object.assign(doc.data, { application_status: 'archived' });
  

      const finalData = merge(
        {
          application_id: _id,
        },
        data,
        candidateData,
        appLog
      );

      return snakecaseToCamelcaseObj(omit(finalData, 'application_key'));
    })
  );
```

I have small filter function which fetches the data from two different schemas, What i am trying to do is i just want to fetch the conditional data and just returned it, But before i return the value, I want to modified one filed name application_status(for custom response), but instead of read, the query is updating value the  table or   collection in database. perticularly this statement,

```
!doc.data.active && Object.assign(doc.data, { application_status: 'archived' });
```

i am updating applications_status value after fetching value from database,localy on back end side, but why it's updating on database side too?

why it's updating value in database in find/read query??